# Which Processes should I add debugger too?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, debugging

I created a web services and added it to IIS 7.5, now I can access it but my code isn't working properly as not returning what i am expecting (logical problem).

Now I opened Visual Studio 2010 but not able to find any process I can attach process to start debugging.

I also tried "Show all processes" and "Show all sessions.."

Which one should i attach it to debug it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to attach the debugger to `w3wp.exe`

Comment: thanks, I tried but it's not getting hit by debugger even though I put latest files in web application's bin

Comment: there might be multiple instances running there. Attach to the other one.

Comment: There isn't any other one, just one there :/

Comment: re-build your entire webservice project and try attaching again

Comment: I was using release build, changing it to debug fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the w3wp.exe process shows up in the list only after accessing it for the first time. Try doing that and then refresh the list.

Another thing to consider is that debugger does not work in "release" config. Make sure it is "debug". Go to menu->build->configuration manager->Active solution configuration.